# How can I can access other users profiles with an authenticated account from url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

On my website I would like to access other users profiles with entering an username in the url,

I'm having some trouble accessing other users informations on their profile while using the authentified account.

The code below always show the authentified user's informations.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', profile_views.UserProfile, name='profile'),
```

**views.py**

```
def UserProfile(request, username):
    u = User.objects.get(username=username)
    user = request.user

    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'account/profile.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**template file**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
</div>
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: `context = {'user': u}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ user.username }}` shows the authenticated user information.

The solution is to change the  context to `{'user': user, 'user_url':u}` then call `{{ user_url.username }}` and it will show the profile of other users.